# setVisible() for cardPanel is not working

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I want to make it so the cardPanels are not visible until an action that is not on the cardPanel is completed. For instance, a window opens up when you select a certain Jradiobutton on that window. I want to use setVisible(boolean) to to do this. However, setVisible is not working for some reason. Is there something i'm missing?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing Refresh Bug?");
    private Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    private JPanel cardPanel = new JPanel();
    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    private Component currentComponent;
    private JButton next;

    MainFrame() {

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // properties of the cardPanel
        cardPanel.setLayout(cardLayout);
        cardPanel.add(new JLabel("One"), "One");
        cardPanel.add(new JLabel("Two"), "Two");
        cardPanel.add(new JLabel("Three"), "Three");
        cardPanel.setVisible(false);

        // Create a radio button
        JRadioButton addNext = new JRadioButton("Add next");

        // Add the radio buttons listener
        addNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "One");
            }
        });

        // Set the layout of the content pane.
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPane.add(cardPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(addNext, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public MainFrame(String title) {

        MainFrame mf = new MainFrame();
    }

}
```

Comment: *"setVisible is not working"* - You never call `cardPanel.setVisible(...)` in your posted code... It works fine for me when I implement that. Please update your example including the `setVisible`-issue. But if this is actually the code producing the issue you're describing I honestly don't understand what the actual problem is... By the way, your class doesn't need to extend `JFrame`, so remove that and change the class name to something else, since it's a bit misleading because you use a seperate `JFrame` instance in your code.

Comment: ok. Where did you implement it. Which line. it doesnt work for me.  I took off the extension.

Comment: Well, it "works" for me assuming I understood the question correctly. I understood it as you want the card panel to be invisible as long as the radio button wasn't pressed. So, if that is correct, I put `cardPanel.setVisible(false);` just where you did and added `cardPanel.setVisible(true);` right before `cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "One");`.

Answer (score 0):

Your class need not extend JFrame, you have already created JFrame in the class, if you want to move accross the cards then change ActionListener as follows

```
addNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             cardLayout.next(cardPanel);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You set your cardPanel not visible by `setVisible(false)` but you never set it to true after, so your cardPanel (containing your cardLayout) is never shown !

If you want your cardLayout to appear when pressing the radiobutton, you just have to add the setVisible(true) in the listener.

You can also use the isSelected() method from JRadioButton to check if it is clicked or not. For example :

```
 addNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(addNext.isSelected()){
                cardPanel.setVisible(true);                
                cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "One");
            }
            else{
                cardPanel.setVisible(false);
                //or : cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "Two");
            }
        }
    });
```

If you want a JFrame to be opened this way, just creat it before, setting it not visible. Then, you set it visible in the listener.

I hope it helped :)

Answer (score -1):

Initialize it in the ActionListener not in the constructor. You must also say setVisible(true) after that. I think you can make CardPannel class which extends JPannel. There is more point of doing it like that. Instead of adding JLabels in the MainFrame constructor do it in the CardPannel constructor. I am on my phone so I can't show you code right now. I hope I helped.